# How to return one of list object in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API?

Tags: list, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, listobject

I am calling a controller API `prodDetails`, it will pass only one parameter called product id:

```
[HttpGet("prodDetails")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<OneOfObject>>> GetProductDetails(string productID)
{
    // get product type from SQL Server database 
    if (productType = 1)
    {
        List<ProdDetailsStandard> listStandard = new List<ProdDetailsStandard>();
        // add list
        return listStandard;
    }

    if (productType = 2)
    {
        List<ProdDetailsVariant> listVariant = new List<ProdDetailsVariant>();
        // add list
        return listVariant; 
    }

    if (productType = 3)
    {
        List<ProdDetailsFancy> listFancy = new List<ProdDetailsFancy>();
        // add list
        return listFancy; 
    }

}
```

I have several list object, so I want to return `List<Object>`based on product type.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @marc_s I updated my content. I am trying to give an sample to understand what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you don't just use `Task<ActionResult<List<Object>>>` as the return type. Do you want the `Object` type must be one of the specified types in (`ProdDetailsStandard`,`ProdDetailsVariant`,`ProdDetailsFancy`....)?

If it is, You can create a base object, Make all the return type extend this base object

```
public class IProdDetails{}

public class ProdDetailsStandard : IProdDetails
{
    //...
}

public class ProdDetailsVariant : IProdDetails
{
    //...
}

public class ProdDetailsFancy : IProdDetails
{
    //...
}
```

Then, in your `GetProductDetails` action, Use the base object as the return type.

```
[HttpGet("prodDetails")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<IProdDetails>>> GetProductDetails(string productID)
{
    // get product type from SQL Server database 
    if (productType == 1)
    {
        List<ProdDetailsStandard> listStandard = new List<ProdDetailsStandard>();
        // add items to list
        return listStandard.Cast<IProdDetails>().ToList();
    }

    if (productType == 2)
    {
        List<ProdDetailsVariant> listVariant = new List<ProdDetailsVariant>();
        // add items to list
        return listVariant.Cast<IProdDetails>().ToList();
    }

    if (productType == 3)
    {
        List<ProdDetailsFancy> listFancy = new List<ProdDetailsFancy>();
        // add items to list
        return listFancy.Cast<IProdDetails>().ToList();
    }

    //.....
}
```

Now, only the object with extend the base object can as the return type. I hope this answer can give you some help.

Comment: yes exactly, it works fine. I tested it. one doubt. what is your suggestion to default return in the last line. It experts return on the last line, other wise compiler error `not all code paths return a value`. But I am not having any other `productType`. I tried `if else` also. it still expect default return on last part of the class. thanks

Comment: @Liamneesan ,In my opinion, When the code access to the last line, it means productType can’t match any options,So I will just  ‘return NotFound()‘ or ’return BadRequest()’